# Dragging in only one direction at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a draggable div now, and I want to make it only draggable in one of the four directions, up,down,left,right, and no draggings with two directions, i.e. up and left is allowed together.

I have tried adding both x and y axis, like this:

```
   $('#element_id').draggable({axis: 'x,y',});
```

but this seems like does nothing, as i want either x or y,but not both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set axis depending draggable direction jQuery draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527002/set-axis-depending-draggable-direction-jquery-draggable)

Comment: For your kind info, if you study closely the API documentation of the widget that it does not support for allowing/disallowing dragging in four directions. And and far as `axis` option is concerned, setting value to `x` means it would only allow to drag horizontally and `y` for allowing vertically. Default it allows in all directions